# mysql filter by day

Tags: php, mysql, date

I am trying to display information for today results only.
The below example i am using displays the information in a 24hour period.

I need to display only the current day information.

**Example :**

```
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) as c 
        FROM toutcome 
        WHERE AffID = '$affID' AND 
        CompletedDate > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY) ";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
echo  $row['c'] ;
```

**I have also tryed**

```
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) as c 
        FROM toutcome 
        WHERE AffID = '$affID' AND 
        CompletedDate > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 24 HOUR) ";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
echo  $row['c'] ;
```

Comment: CompletedDate >=CURDATE ()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as c FROM toutcome WHERE AffID = '$affID' AND CompletedDate BETWEEN CURDATE() AND NOW()
```

If you know `CompletedDate` will never be in the future then:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as c FROM toutcome WHERE AffID = '$affID' AND CompletedDate >= CURDATE()
```

Arun's solution wouldn't use an index on `CompletedDate`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
 as c FROM toutcome 
WHERE AffID = '$affID' 
AND 
TIMESTAMPDIFF(
    DAY,
    DATE(CompletedDate),
    DATE(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
) = 1
```